# MS Bot builder IForm Invalid Type Exception:Has xxx Expect yyy

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to build a Simple iForm Based bot. When one Form is completed I want to show another. 
Both Forms consist of a single enum value. The first form show correctly. When I select a option, the `SelectNextAction` is called as expected.
The first dialog is constructed via:

```
  public static IForm<RootForm> BuildRootForm()
    {
        IForm<RootForm> ret  = new FormBuilder<RootForm>()
             .Message("Hi")
             .AddRemainingFields()
             .OnCompletion(SelectNextAction)
                .Build();

        return ret;
    }

    private static async Task SelectNextAction(IDialogContext context, RootForm state)
    {

        // Tell the user that the form is complete
        switch (state.Choice)
        {
            case MainChoice.Transfer:
                IFormDialog<TransferForm> form = FormDialog.FromForm(TransferForm.BuildTransferForm);
                context.Call(form, TransferDialogComplete);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

After this code has run `TransferDialogComplete` is called:

```
   private async static Task TransferDialogComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<TransferForm> result)
    {
        await result;
    }
```

And then a Exception is thrown:

> Exception: invalid type: expected EBBot.Dialogs.TransferForm, have
>   RootForm [File of type 'text/plain']

What am I doing wrong? any idea or suggestions?

Comment: please expand the code so the scenario can be fully understood. Show the dialogs and how the forms are being called. Where the "state" variable  in the method NextTask is being used?

Comment: Is SelectNextAction the "ResumeAfter<T>" method of the previous form call?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm using onCompletion -  I have updated the question.

Comment: mm I think that could be the issue. I would recommend calling the second form on the "ResumeAfter" of the call to the first form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the issue is due to the call of the second form in the `OnCompletion` call.

In order to solve this, you should call the second form in the `ResumeAfter<T`> method that you specified when you call your first form.

#### Code calling RootForm

```
var rootForm = FormDialog.FromForm(RootForm.BuildRootForm);
context.Call(rootForm, AfterRootFormCompleted);
```

#### Code to execute after RootForm completes

```
private async Task AfterRootFormCompleted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<RootForm> result)
{
     try 
     {
        var state = await result;
        IFormDialog<TransferForm> form = FormDialog.FromForm(TransferForm.BuildTransferForm);
        context.Call(form, TransferDialogComplete);
     }
     catch (FormCancelledException)
     {
      // do something;
     }
}
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

The delegate passed into the `OnCompletion` method can not be used to call another forms or any other dialogs.

> This should only be used for side effects such as calling your service wit the form state results.  In any case the completed form state will be passed to the parent dialog.

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/IFormBuilder.cs): line 225

For an example look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/ff6f0159e7207fb228620af9d6a49b960a4c9c3a/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot/AnnotatedSandwich.cs).

How you can implement this is through the `ResumeAfter` method. Here is an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var form = new FormDialog<SimpleForm>(new SimpleForm1(), 
        SimpleForm1.BuildForm);
        context.Call(form, ResumeAfterForm1);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterForm1(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var form = new FormDialog<SimpleForm2>(new SimpleForm2(), 
        SimpleForm2.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call(form, ResumeAfterForm2);
    }
    // other code
}
```

**Note**: I used the `PromptInStart` Because I have noticed that if you don't include this the form will not start right away.

Comment: PromptInStart option. nice detail!